# Taking samples with variable length

Tags: r, loops, random

```
ns<-c(1,5,20,50,100,1000,10000)
Final<-rep(0,7)
second<-rep(0,10000)
for(i in length(ns)) {
second<-sample(1:1000,ns[i],replace=TRUE)
second[second==0]<-NA
Final[i]<- sd(second,na.rm=FALSE)
}
```

`ns` is the different sampling lengths I want to take. I created empty vectors `Final` and `second` to store values for my loop.

I was encountering issues where `Final` was returning mostly 0 values, so after thinking for a bit I decided to have all the zero values deleted from `second` every loop. But it hasn't helped, after running this code I get:

```
> Final
[1]   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000 288.569
```

Now I'm stuck. Because when I read my code it seems very clear: Take a sample from 1:1000 of the number of units corresponding to the [i] of `ns`, given the *i*th loop. Then take the standard deviation of the nonzero values of the vector containing the sample and store it in another vector, `Final`.

Comment: Typical issue with `for` loop, which should be written as `for(i in 1:length(ns))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is the for-loop:

```
for(i in length(ns)) {
```

The expression `length(ns)` returns a single number, which is the length of vector `ns`, which is 7. Hence the loop will only be executed once with `i=7`.

The best way to loop along a vector is to use [`seq_along()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html):

```
for (i in seq_along(ns)) {
```

---

Also note that the expression

```
rep(0,N)
```

can be replaced with

```
double(N)
```

since the default element value for a new double vector is zero. This form is also more idiomatic, as it expresses the intention of constructing a new vector to be used later.

Comment: Thank you - as well as Psidom. Nice to know that I was very close. And I'll keep those two functions in mind, they do seem to be more to the point to me.